# Replace inner Javascript for loop without using loop, instead maybe use map , filter, reduce?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I have 2 loops, the outer loop is already part of existing code... but the new loop I don't know if it is slower, uglier or what..  but I suppose I am just wanting to be into modern js with map/reduce/filter etc...

Instead of showing real code,  this sample should be enough to explain the code

```
var master = ['hhhh', 'yyyy']

var array = ['adf','hhhh','jjj']


for (index = 0; index < master.length; index++) { 
    //console.log(master[index]); 

    for (index2 = 0; index2 < array.length; index2++) { 

       //console.log(array[index2]); 

       if(master[index] === array[index2]){
          console.log(array[index2]);
       }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Why does your title ask for "*without using loop map , filter, reduce*"?

Comment: So you need build-in js method like map or reduce or no?

Comment: No, this sample is not enough. Logging the values is mostly pointless and should be done differently. What's the actual use case?

Comment: updated the title...    -  I don't understand why samples are not enough @Bergi      the master one ...  comes from data from database.... and existing code is a loop,  the inner loop, ... that the the array of what will be a hard coded list of values that need to match based on what I'm told to use by product owner.   I don't know what else to do to really demonstrate it.   seems like others are making some decent attempts that I need to go through   thx

Comment: @JeremyMiller Knowing that one list is dynamic and the other is hardcoded is important info already, thanks. But what are you going to do with the results of this loop? Do you really just want to output the elements? Because for that, a simple loop is the proper approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the map method to iterate over arrays like this:

```
var master = ['hhhh', 'yyyy']
var array = ['adf','hhhh','jjj']
for (index = 0; index < master.length; index++) { 
    //console.log(master[index]); 
    array.map(function(element){
        if(master[index] == element){
            console.log(element);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: No. Do not use `map` "to iterate". It's used to create new arrays, but you're not using that here. You should use `forEach` instead, or rather, an ordinary loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like the intersection of two arrays. That is the common between two arrays. You can do it by using `filter` and `indexOf`.

```js
var master = ['hhhh', 'yyyy'];
var array = ['adf','hhhh','jjj'];

const common = array.filter(item => master.indexOf(item) > -1);

console.log(common);
```

Comment: If you need the outer loop then your code is more than okay. Use a for loop instead of `map` or `forEach` in this case because `for` loop is faster and you don't need anything else here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method if you need intersection

```
let intersection = master .filter(x => array .includes(x));
```